# Gradle: How to add output jar file into an existing war file

Tags: gradle, war

I have a working gradle build file that builds a jar file into the /build/libs directory. This works fine. However, I want to add a task that takes this jar file and packages it into an existing war file (into the WEB-INF/libs directory inside). How do I add this task?

Comment: For the good of your own sanity, don't do this!  To modify WEB-INF/libs directory of a war is to change the dependencies of a web application that has already been built, which potentially exposes you to very difficult to find and resolve errors depending on how you change that jar.  It is much safer (and easier) to declare your jar as a dependency of that war and rebuilding the war in the event that your jar changes something important.  This way, if you dependency jar does change in a way that breaks the war, you'll know exactly what broke before you deploy the war.

Comment: I get all that, and I understand the implications. In this case it's generally safer and I don't want to have to rebuild the existing war.

Answer (score 0):

I did this like the following:

```
def originalWar = file("../release/${sesame_version}/war/openrdf-sesame.war")
def outputDir = "./build/war"
def outputDirSesame = "$outputDir/sesame"

task extractWar(type: Copy) {
    from zipTree(originalWar)
    into "$outputDirSesame"
    outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
}

task copyJar(type: Copy, dependsOn: extractWar) {  
    from "./build/libs"
    into "$outputDirSesame/WEB-INF/lib"
    outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
}

task buildWar(type: Zip, dependsOn: copyJar) {
    archiveName "openrdf-sesame.war"
    destinationDir file("$outputDir")
    from "$outputDirSesame"
    outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
}

build.dependsOn buildWar
```